# Is there any general method to solve a Second order ODE with variable coefficient of the form $a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'(x)+c(x)y(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there any general method to solve a Second order ODE with variable coefficient of the form $a(x)y''(x)+b(x)y'(x)+c(x)y(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

The equation you have is a second order *linear homogeneous* ODE. 
It can be rewritten as 
$$ y''(x) + b_1(x)\, y'(x) + c_1(x) y(x) = 0, $$
where 
$b_1 = b/a$ and $c_1 = c/a$ with $a \neq 0$.

A general solution of second order linear homogeneous ODE can be obtained in multiple ways, including integration and series expansion.

I propose to read [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Second-OrderOrdinaryDifferentialEquation.html) to get an overview of possible ways to solve it.

Comment: I was mulling this over and do you think that it would be appropriate to call the second order ODE non-degenerate if $a\neq 0$?

Comment: @Tucker Yes, this is exactly what nondegeneracy condition means.

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully approach the problem submitted, the 'Reduction of Order' technique should prove quite useful.  Here is a short video that will demonstrate how to solve such a problem with this method:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQSFW8BIrY0&t=627s

Comment: Although the video can be useful, your answer should be self-contained. (although it does mention the name of the technique)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.

Even an equation as simple as Airy's equation:
$$
y''-xy=0,
$$
can NOT be solved. Meaning, its solutions can not be expressed in closed form, as expressions of simple functions, their compositions and integrals.

The only method which always produces an answer is the method of power series, which works if all the coefficients are expressible as power series (i.e., real analytic).

Comment: Since when does "solve" means to "write a solution in closed form"? It is a completely imprecise answer.